# How to selective change modal backdrop in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have two modals. When the first is opened, the background should be grayed out, as is default. But this should not happen with the second one. The code is:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(type = 'text/css', '.modal-backdrop { display: none }'),

  actionButton('modal1', 'Modal1'),
  actionButton('modal2', 'Modal2'),
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$modal1,
    showModal(modalDialog(title = "Modal1"))
  )

  observeEvent(input$modal2,
    showModal(modalDialog(title = "Modal2"))
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The css code should be connected to the id of the second modal dialog, but it is not possible to include an id in the function 'modalDialog'.

Any ideas about how to apply the css code selectively to only the second modal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add JS code to hide the backdrop after showing the second modal using `tags$script` just after `modalDialog`.

```R
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('modal1', 'Modal1'),
  actionButton('modal2', 'Modal2'),
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(input$modal1,
    showModal(modalDialog(title = "Modal1"))
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$modal2, {
    showModal(
      list(
        modalDialog(title = "Modal2"),
        tags$script("$('.modal-backdrop').css('display', 'none');")
      )
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```